# Bash alias function with predefined argument

Tags: bash

I have an alias `gl` which is an wrapper for `git log`.

Basically like this

```bash
function gitLog(){
  if [ $# -eq 0 ]
    then
      git log 
    else
      git log -n $1
}

alias gl=gitLog
```

I want to add an alias which just calls `gitLog` with an argument like this

```
alias gl10=gitLog(10)
```

I don't want to pass the argument from the command line. It shall just be a handy shortcut.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply, add it in your `.bashrc` like:

```
alias gl10="gitLog 10"
```

To apply the changes: `source ~/.bashrc`